# How to stop logback-classic from reappearing in m2 repository when running mvn package

Tags: spring, maven, package, pom.xml, slf4j

I am running into the following error when loading the application context

```sh
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:.../repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.30/slf4j-nop-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:.../repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
```

and since I want to keep slf4j, which comes with Lombok, I tried deleting the folder `logback-classic/1.2.3`. But it keeps coming back whenever I run `mvn package`, so there's gotta be something in my pom that's reinstalling it, but it's never specifically referenced so there has to be some inheritance hullaballoo happening.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>**********</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <endpoints.project.id>**********</endpoints.project.id>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [START api_management] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [END api_management] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.80</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- deploy configuration -->
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                    <version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- [START endpoints_plugin] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- plugin configuration -->
                    <hostname>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</hostname>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- [END endpoints_plugin] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If anyone could help finding the problematic dependency or help me figure out how to find it and get rid of the slf4j error, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering here cause comments are to short: (Not yet a final answer):

It is coming back cause it's a transitive dependency of `spring-boot-starter` ... or more accurate `spring-boot-starter` has a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-logging` which has the dependency on `logback-classic`
which is the [default for spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging).

Furthermore I don't see [slf4j in lombok project](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.12/jar)

one more thing the first dependency [`endpoints-framework` contains the reference to slf4j-nop](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework/2.2.1/jar) which is from my point of view wrong.

Apart from all above the configured versions-maven-plugin and binding it to the `compile` phase does not make sense which makes your build very slow....

Comment: i stole it from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend/pom.xml - you recommend getting rid of it?

Comment: It does not make sense to add versions-maven-plugin in the compile phase cause it's a reporting goal. Either you call directly on plain command line or related to reporting (site generation) but not during a normal run...